# Javascript call is being ignored

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am currently working on an advanced view page that display results for a set of data in Asp.NET MVC. I am having a problem with javascript. I have only used a small amount of javascript, so I am still learning. My code seems to go right over the call. I understand it is most likely horrible coding to include a script inside an if statement, but that seemed like the only solution to avoid a NullReferenceException.

**This code is being used to not only redirect the user to another page, but also open the file.**

```
     @if(item.PDFLink.GetValueOrDefault() != 0)
                    { 
                    <script>
                        function showfile() {
                            window.open(@Url.Action("PDF", new { byteData = @item.PDF.id }));
                            }
                    </script>
                    }
                    @if(item.PDFLink.GetValueOrDefault() != 0)
                    { 
                           @Html.ActionLink("text", "Display", null, new { onclick = "return showfile();"})
                    }
```

Comment: Hit F12 and open the Developer Tools console. It could be that you have another Javascript syntax error somewhere that is halting the script engine.

Comment: And why are you only writing your "showFile()" function if the PDFLink has a value? I'd write the function to the page no matter what.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, I am wanting the page to only show the link to the PDF if there is a PDF. I don't want a link unless there is a PDF. This is why I have the @Html.ActionLink in the if statement.

Comment: I don't think it's your problem, but it is customary to use <script type="text/javascript">

Comment: I checked out the developer view, and it shows the "/testdata/PDF/byteData=4", which is exactly what I want it to do. For some reason it just won't open the window. I click the link, and I am just returned the actual actionlink page (Display), without it giving me the file. I was following this File/View return pattern. WestDiscGolfs example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663480/in-asp-mvc-how-can-i-return-a-new-view-and-a-file-to-the-user

Comment: I guess it could be an issue with the IF statement that is containing the script tag. But I don't see a way around that. The if statement is making sure that a NullReferenceException doesn't occur, and the script section needs to be in that location, so that the @item from the ForEach loop can be used adequately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my own problem after puzzling over this...

I wanted to basically open another view and the file, so that the user did not lose the page they were currently on.

I scrapped all the javascript, and instead used this:

```
<a href="..." target="_blank"></a>
```

This opens the file in a new window, while keeping my current view. Pretty interesting how easy this solution actually was. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no reason to use the helper in this case. Since all you want it to do is to point a javascript function.

Change

```
@Html.ActionLink("text", "Display", null, new { onclick = "return showfile();" })
```

To

```
<a href="#" onclick="return showfile();">text</a>
```

Unless I'm missing something this is all you need.

Comment: That should work. I replaced the entire line with that code. I am starting to think for some reason the code doesn't execute the javascript due to the If statement. What do you think?