# Success and failure actions when downloading a file in MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, download

A button on my page calls a controller method that returns a file, like so:

```
// Update number of downloads in database
// Return the file
return File(filedata, contentType);
```

In the view, this button is defined as:

```
<img onclick="location.href ='@Url.Action("DownloadVersion", new { fileVersionId = version.FileVersionId })'" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/download.png")", alt="Download" title="Download"/>
```

I need an element on my page to update dynamically with the number of downloads once the download has started. At the moment I have no way of informing the page to update. Currently I don't see a way of doing this.

I have tried calling the controller method via ajax instead so I get the success and error callbacks, however this seems to mean that the browser never actually downloads the file (I have read in other posts that this seems to be a limitation of ajax).

Unfortunately, a direct link to the file is not an option. The download has to occur via the controller method so that the user does not have access to the file url path (to check if they are authorized to download it).

Is there a viable solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something similar to - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3667379/33116 - you can then instead of redirecting you can do a request to a web api end point which can return the download count and update an element with the returned value.