# Download ZIP file and output Rotativa PDF in browser ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, dotnetzip, rotativa

I am working on a report which requires multiple PDF files to download in one zip file and as well as create a new PDF file and save that new created file on server as well. I am using `DotNetZip` and `Rotativa` for zip and pdf files.

Currently i have this in my `Controller`:

```
[HttpGet]  
public ActionResult GetReport()  
{  
   var test2 = new ActionAsPdf("ContractorReportNew");
   var zip = new ZipFile();  
   zip.AddFile("MyFile.zip", "Orders");  
   string zipName = string.Format("Contractor Report{0}.zip", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy-HH:mm:ss"));
   using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
   {
     zip.Save(memoryStream);
     return File(memoryStream.ToArray(), "application/zip", zipName);
   }
}
```

And

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ContractorReportNew()  
{  
   //Data from DB  
   var test = new ViewAsPdf("Contractor_report")
   {
      MinimumFontSize = 14,
      PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Landscape,
      PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,
   };

     var abc = test.BuildFile(this.ControllerContext);
     System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, abc);
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(abc);
     return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");
}
```

How can i achieve what i need?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What advice do you actually need? You’ve put a few bits of code and that’s it.

Comment: I want to download the zip file (this part is working fine). I also want show PDF in my browser and download that pdf as well (this part is not working). Sorry my question is not clear.

Comment: You can show the PDF by showing it in an iFrame. You can make your browser request this in a GET request. If you're using HTTPS you could save the generated PDF in a session variable so you don't generate it again, alternatively you could just return the file as newly generated PDF.

Comment: Can you please show me how to do it? I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it work by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3663480/in-asp-mvc-how-can-i-return-a-new-view-and-a-file-to-the-user) example.
Now i have this in my code:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Test Me", "Contractor_report", "Admin", new { @contractor_id = 1 }, new { @onclick = "TestFunction()" })
```

and then:

```
function TestFunction() {
  window.open('@Url.Action("ContractorReportNew", "Admin")')
}
```